# Infinity scroller sent 20-30 request at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made an infinity scroller. here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function next_page(url_no){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/bc-m-home?page=' + String(url_no) /* http://127.0.0.1:5000/bc-m-home?page=2 */
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#new_post').append(data);
    })
    event.preventDefault();
}

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight-1000) {
        if ( Number("{{last_page}}") > Number(document.getElementById("url_no").innerHTML) ){   /* {{last_page}} contain the last page number and "document.getElementById("url_no").innerHTML" contain the next page number. In this time the next page number is 2 . */
            next_page(document.getElementById("url_no").innerHTML)
            document.getElementById("url_no").innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById("url_no").innerHTML) +1 /* here I increase the next page number */
            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

But the problem is when I reach the bottom of the page it calls "next_page" function 20-30 times. for this reason ajax sent a lot of requests at a time.

but I want, when a request will be sent user will get some post. And when the user reached the bottom again then a request will send again. Not 20-30 requests at a time.

Comment: dont use old school page height, use the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and look out for a div at bottom of page, once seen load more, if there is no more set a flag to prevent loading more

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you very much. It worked